# Some pages repeatedly parse the same JSON over and over again

Tags: bug, review

I had left my browser open at the beta review screen (where it says "there are no more items left for you to review") while I was doing something else. However I soon noticed that the PC's fan was struggling, and sure enough checking Task Manager showed that the browser was consuming CPU. Navigating to another page (e.g. Questions) made the problem go away.

I then noticed the same thing happening on the User page for Community. This time I had a bit of luck with my C++ debugger - I was able to find that the page was continually reparsing the same 6MB of JSON. (I said 3MB in a comment but I forgot that JS chars are UTF16). I had tried using a JavaScript profiler but I couldn't get it to give me anything more accurate than the source URL and line number.

Is there some reason why there is code on the page that is continually parsing the same string? I couldn't see anything obviously happening - I wasn't even interacting with the page and it was still consuming CPU.

Comment: Its simple Auto-Refresh feature. Just like you get new question's notification on main page.

Comment: @Lucifer but I don't see any CPU being consumed on other pages...

Comment: This is browser issue. What browser you have?

Comment: If Chrome, [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129748) might be related.

Comment: My debugger suggests that there's a repeating 1s [why 1s?] timeout at around line 44 of http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/review.js, unfortunately the code there takes my browser 1.1s to execute.

Comment: Most of that is taken up by repeatedly parsing the same 3MB of JSON...

Comment: Why do you ignore comments? What browser do you have? It's really not hard to answer.

Comment: +1 to counter children's downvotes

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Does "Gecko 4 based browser" and "Gecko 18 based browser" suffice?

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach I downvoted because the bug report is incomplete and not helpful. The first step to debugging is almost always to reproduce the problem, and by not providing the browser the OP is making it exceedingly hard to verify this bug report (I just tried it, and can't - 3 *mega*bytes is a lot of data, and I just can't find that data from the files the page loads or in any of the client-side storage spaces)

Comment: @Neil No, it unfortunately does not. Does your browser not have an About box with the version number and name of the software? You can usually find this in Help/About (Apple/About on OSX). If you're rolling your own browser, then it's up to you to debug this behaviour, not MSO.

Comment: @TimYiJiang If you think Stack Overflow shouldn't be trying to store 3 million characters of data, then I'm willing to log a new question for that part of the problem, and I even have sample data captured, although I don't have anywhere I can easily upload it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The History plugin used by the review queue sets up a function to save data to sessionStorage on an interval of `History.options.storeInterval` milliseconds. This is apparently a workaround for an issue with Internet Explorer where using handlers on `beforeunload` and `unload` wasn't always producing the desired results.

According to the source comments, both the normal approach and the workaround are enabled on all browsers for the sake of consistency, even though the latter is only needed for Internet Explorer. This would make the behaviour technically [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), albeit unnecessary in your case.

I'd have to take a deeper look to see if there's perhaps a cleaner solution to the problem the plugin is trying to solve, but for the meantime I did [throw together a small userscript](https://github.com/tms/stack-utilities/blob/master/stack-utilities-history-hack.user.js) which will allow you to disable the problem code for other (userscript-supporting) browsers*.

<sub>*This shouldn't impact the functionality of the page at all, but it goes without saying that if anyone runs into problems with the review queue and is also using this script, they should disable it and confirm any issues persist before reporting them as bugs on Meta.</sub>

Comment: It's been so long since I used Internet Explorer that I didn't even know that it supported session storage!

Comment: Yep, as of version 8 it seems.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to simplify your user script to the following bookmarklet: `javascript:clearInterval(History.intervalList.shift())`

Comment: In fact the same fix also seems to apply to the User page too!

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` was slow because I was using a testing build that not only does extra bounds checking during `JSON.parse` but also had compiler optimisations disabled. This means that even on my fast PC it can only parse a shade under 11 million characters per second.

By comparison if you remove the bounds checking only it improves to over 18 million cps; if you enable compiler optimisations only then it improves significantly to over 122 million cps while if you do both then you get a top speed of over 162 million cps.

Note that the JSON parse wasn't responsible for all of the CPU usage but it was the single largest contributor.

Comment: This might really be a bug, but we *really* need to know what browser you are using to do anything with it. Please provide that info. Your not providing that info may be the reason for your downvotes.